# jsf core validator error on a specific page

Tags: java, jsf, exception, validation, jsf-1.2

I am using **jsf 1.2** with **adf** to create an application.

The application runs great in the local weblogic server 11g.

But when I deploy on oracle enterprise manager I get an error on loading a specific page:

```
    <21-may-2014 16H34' CEST> <Warning> <oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl> <BEA-000000> <ADF_FACES-60098: The Faces lifecycle exceptions receives untreated RENDER_RESPONSE 6
javax.faces.FacesException: javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Not nested in a tag of proper type. Error for tag with handler class:com.sun.faces.taglib.jsf_core.ValidatorTag 
at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.dispatch(ExternalContextImpl.java:415)

at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.context.ExternalContextDecorator.dispatch(ExternalContextDec orator.java:44)

at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.context.ExternalContextDecorator.dispatch(ExternalContextDecorator.java:44)

at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.config.rich.RecordRequestAttributesDuringDispatch.dispatch(RecordRequestAttributesDuringDispatch.java:44)

at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.context.ExternalContextDecorator.dispatch(ExternalContextDecorator.java:45)

at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.context.ExternalContextDecorator.dispatch(ExternalContextDecorator.java:45)

at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.context.ExternalContextDecorator.dispatch(ExternalContextDecorator.java:45)

at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.context.FacesContextFactoryImpl$OverrideDispatch.dispatch(FacesContextFactoryImpl.java:268)

at com.sun.faces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.executePageToBuildView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:471)
.......................
```

Which I can understand that there is a tag not in its place, relating with validator?

The only validator in my page is put here:

```
<af:inputText value="#{row.bindings.DocumName.inputValue}"
    label="#{bindings.DocumentsPresentProcessVVO2.hints.DocumName.label}"
    required="#{bindings.DocumentsPresentProcessVVO2.hints.DocumName.mandatory}"
    columns="#{bindings.DocumentsPresentProcessVVO2.hints.DocumName.displayWidth}"
    maximumLength="#{bindings.DocumentsPresentProcessVVO2.hints.DocumName.precision}"
    shortDesc="#{bindings.DocumentsPresentProcessVVO2.hints.DocumName.tooltip}"
    id="it1" readOnly="true">
    <f:validator binding="#{row.bindings.DocumName.validator}" />
</af:inputText>
```

Isn't there, where it should be?

```
<f:validator binding="#{row.bindings.DocumName.validator}" />
```

Or I am interpreting the exception wrongly?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe `<af:inputText>` doesn't accept `<f:validator>` but a custom tag for validator. Also, check if `<af:inputText>` has a `validator` attribute. I can't provide an exact answer since I never worked with ADF.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza It has a validator attribute . . .

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza  You mean like this: <af:inputText validator="#{row.bindings.DocumName.validator}" value=....

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Post an answer, for me to accept